# Difference between cv2, scipy.misc and skimage

Tags: python, opencv, scipy, scikit-image

What is the main difference between

- `cv2.imread / resize/ imwrite`
- `scipy.misc.imread / imresize/ imsave`
- `skimage.io.imread / skimage.transform.resize / skimage.io.imsave`

and how to decide which one to use?

I know `cv2` and `skimage` have different [encoder](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/2293#issuecomment-245585628), and `cv2` use 'BGR' not 'RGB' in default. But sometimes a script might use them together, for example [main.py](https://github.com/umich-vl/pose-ae-demo/blob/master/main.py), where it uses `scipy.misc.imread`, `cv2.imresize` and `cv2.imwrite`. I am wondering the reason to do so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `scipy.misc` module exists historically as a place to gather functions that do not fit easily into the other SciPy submodules.  It is slated for deprecation and should not be used.

In the Python ecosystem, I'd recommend `imageio` for reading images (or `matplotlib.pyplot.imread`, if you already are using `matplotlib`).

Scikit-image provides a convenient wrapper around all of these I/O libraries as `skimage.io` (it should pick up whatever is installed on your system already).  It also ensures that images are converted to the correct data type and range formats for use with other skimage functions (see http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html).

`cv2.imread` et al. operate on OpenCV image objects and, as you've already observed, those images are typically stored in `BGR` memory layout.  But for loading PNGs and JPGs, most of these libraries listed above all wrap the same underlying C libraries, perhaps with slightly different parameters for compression etc.

I'd recommend that you use whichever functions minimize the dependency footprint of your script / package.